# Keyboard language is changed when xrandr is executed

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xrandr

I have two scripts to switch between my standing desk and my sitting desk which are:

```
#!/bin/bash   
xrandr --auto && xrandr --output eDP1 --off;
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash  
xrandr --auto && xrandr --output HDMI1 --off;
```

The problem is everytime I switch displays, the current keyboard layout changes. I need to have two distinct layouts because my laptop keyboard is different from the external one.

Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 2 keyboard layouts, do the following:

You need to install `xdotool` with `sudo apt-get install xdotool` for this.

Modify your scripts to the following.

```
#!/bin/bash   
xrandr --auto && xrandr --output eDP1 --off;
xdotool keydown Super key space keyup Super
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash   
xrandr --auto && xrandr --output HDMI1 --off;
xdotool keydown Super key space keyup Super
```